# Using Buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, button

How can you create a button so that whenever you click on it a question changes to its uppercase form, then when you click the button again it changes to its lowercase form. I believe I should create a function of some sort, just not sure how. Below is what I have tried so far:

```
function upper_lower() {
  if (windows.document.f1.value=="lower") {
    windows.document.value = "UPPER"
    windows.document.question = windows.document.question.toUpperCase();
    windows.document.queston.size="40"
  } else {
    windows.document.value = "lower"
    windows.document.question = windows.document.question.toLowerCase()
    windows.document.queston.size="30"
  }
}
```

Question

```
<input type="text" name="question" value="Favorite food?" size="25">
```

readonly /input

```
<input type="button" name="f1" value="UPPER" onClick = "upper_lower">
```

Comment: use toggle feature by adding some flag and convert `string.toUpperCase()` or `lowerCase()` basis of flag

Comment: Is the HTML you gave correct? It seems your missing some brackets `< >`.

Comment: You are correct; it is missing some brackets! Sorry! Novice to JavaScript; just started learning last week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html:

```
Question <input type="text" name="question" id="question1" value="Favorite food?" size="25" readonly></input> 
<input type="button" name="f1" id="button1" value="UPPER" onClick="upper_lower()"></input>
```

js:

```
var toggle = true;
function upper_lower(){
    var question = document.getElementById('question1'),
        button = document.getElementById('button1');
    if(toggle){
        question.value = question.value.toUpperCase();
        button.value = 'LOWER';
        toggle = false; 
    } else{
        question.value = question.value.toLowerCase();
        button.value = 'UPPER';
        toggle = true;
    }
}
```

Snippet below (indented weird for some reason)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 Question <input type="text" name="question" id="question1" value="Favorite food?" size="25" readonly></input> 
 <input type="button" name="f1" id="button1" value="UPPER" onClick="upper_lower()"></input>
</body>

<script>
var toggle = true;
function upper_lower(){
 var question = document.getElementById('question1'),
  button = document.getElementById('button1');
 if(toggle){
  question.value = question.value.toUpperCase();
  button.value = 'LOWER';
  toggle = false; 
 } else{
  question.value = question.value.toLowerCase();
  button.value = 'UPPER';
  toggle = true;
 }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Updated Code...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var flag = 0;
    function changecase() {     

        if (flag == 0) {

            document.form1.instring.value = document.form1.instring.value.toUpperCase();
            document.form1.Convert.value = 'To Lower'
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            document.form1.instring.value = document.form1.instring.value.toLowerCase();
            document.form1.Convert.value = 'To Upper'
            flag = 0;
        }


    }
</script>



      <form name="form1" method="post">
        <input name="instring" type="text" value="this is the text string" size="30">
        <input type="button" name="Convert" value="To Upper " onclick="changecase();">

        </form>
```

Comment: Doesn't this create a new box that outputs the changed code? I was hoping to just switch the case in the original box instead of creating a new one.